# how to avoid looping in this code

Tags: algorithm, matlab

I'm wondering if anyone can propose an alternate way to write this code that avoids looping?  Thanks!

```
for j=1:Ncol-1

    for i=nr:Nitr
        mydataD(k,1) = j;
        mydataD(k,2) = i;
        mydataD(k,3) = D(j,i); 
        k=k+1;
    end
    nr=nr+1;
end

[w,T] = kruskal(mydataD);
```

Comment: I didn't know Matlab had a built-in function for Kruskal's algorithm. Are you trying to pass it a sparse matrix?

Comment: What is `D`, a function or a matrix?

Answer (score 1):

```
[r,c]=find(tril(D.',-1));
mydataD=[c,r,D(sub2ind(size(D),c,r))];
```

The transpose and swapped row/column are so that the row numbers are sorted. This doesn't include elements whose values are zero. If you actually want the zero values we'll have to change the first line:

```
[r,c]=find(tril(ones(size(D),-1));
mydataD=[c,r,D(sub2ind(size(D),c,r))];
```

This looks to me to be an attempted replacement for sparse matrices, changing from an adjacency matrix to an adjacency list. The equivalent sparse matrix would be:

```
mydataD=sparse(triu(D,1));
```

Answer (score 0):

To avoid the loop you could do something like this:

```
    mydataD = zeros(Ncol -1, 3);
    i = linspace(1, Ncol -1, Ncol -1);
    j = linspace(nr,Niter, Ncol -1);
    mydataD(:,1) = i;
    mydataD(:,2) = j; 
    mydataD(:,3) = D(j,i);
```